# threading/multiprocessing/Queue?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multiprocessing

I need to add two (A & B) big random size (10^7 , 10^12) of vector with the help of two threads in python or multiprocessing. and then need to store it in C. I have to Time my code as well. and at last need to find minimum and average number from the final vector. I have tried so many things and currently working on Anaconda Jupyter notebook. It accept the code but not giving me any output.

this is my code

```
"import time
 import multiprocessing
 import numpy as np
 import threading
 add_result = [] 
 a = np.random.rand(10000000)
 b = np.random.rand(10000000)
 def calc_add(numbers):
 global add_results
 for n in numbers:
    print('add' + str(a+b)) 
    add_result.append(a+b)
    print('within a process result' +str(add_result))
    time.Time = start_time
if __name__=="__main__":
arr = a+b
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = calc_add, args = (arr))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = calc_add, args = (arr))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()

print("result" +str(add_result))
print("done!")
```

Comment: Please put your code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this kind of operations with multiprocessing, because (in Python) Processes are separate  and don't share anything between themselves. That means your `global`variable is only global in the second process `p1`, which is why your add_result`variable is still equal to "[]".

Please add your code in your question so we can help you re-writing it.

You should also take a look at python's [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) to better understand why processes (and threads) can't help you with your task.